# SuiteScript 2.1 dialog.confirm(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, promise, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to write a UserEvent script which prompts the user for a confirmation when they attempt to edit a sales order which has already had it's picking ticket printed. Below is my code:

```js
define(['N/record', 'N/search', 'N/log', 'N/runtime', 'N/ui/dialog'], function (record, search, log, runtime, dialog) {
    /**
    *@NApiVersion 2.1
    *@NScriptType UserEventScript
    */

    var result = true;

function beforeSubmit(context) {
    
    var order = context.oldRecord;

    var orderStatus = order.getValue({fieldId: "status"});

    if(orderStatus != "Billed") {
        var orderInternalID = order.getValue({fieldId: "id"});
        log.debug("id", orderInternalID);

        var systemnoteSearchObj = search.create({
            type: "systemnote",
            filters:
            [
            ["recordid","equalto",String(orderInternalID)], 
            "AND", 
            ["field","anyof","TRANDOC.BPRINTEDPICKINGTICKET"], 
            "AND", 
            ["newvalue","is","T"]
            ],
            columns:
            [
            search.createColumn({
                name: "record",
                sort: search.Sort.ASC,
                label: "Record"
            }),
            search.createColumn({name: "name", label: "Set by"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "date", label: "Date"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "context", label: "Context"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "type", label: "Type"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "field", label: "Field"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "oldvalue", label: "Old Value"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "newvalue", label: "New Value"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "role", label: "Role"})
            ]
        });
        var searchResultCount = systemnoteSearchObj.runPaged().count;
        log.debug("systemnoteSearchObj result count",Number(searchResultCount));

        if(Number(searchResultCount) > 0) {
            var options = {
                title: 'WARNING: Pick Ticket Printed',
                message: 'The pick ticket has already been printed for this sales order. Are you sure you want to edit?'
            };

            dialog.confirm(options).then(confirm).catch(cancel);
        }
    }
   
    log.debug("result", result);
    return result;
}

function confirm(reason) {
    log.debug("User confirmed save.", reason);
    result = true;

    return true;
}

function cancel(reason) {
    log.debug("User cancelled save.", reason);
    result = false;

    return false;
}

return {

    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
}
});
```

When I deploy this script on the Edit event and try to edit and save the order, I get no confirmation dialog and instead receive the following error:
`TypeError: dialog.confirm(...).then is not a function [at Object.beforeSubmit`. From what I've seen, this type of error occurs when you attempt to use .then() on a function which does not return a promise. However, in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4497799943.html) for dialog.confirm(), it clearly states that the function does in fact return a promise.

Why am I receiving this error and how can I avoid it to achieve the goal of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A User Event script runs on the server side and thus cannot render UI components (there's no browser instance or `window` object to render on). You'll likely need to transition this logic to the `saveRecord` event of a Client Script.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks!